# Finish a file early by writing a char

Tags: c, linux, file

I did some experiments, but could not find a way to do that : Is there a way to tell the system to "finish a file" early ?

Like, writing some weird old looking char that will, somehow, be interpreted as "Well, this is the end of this file." by the Linux kernel.

The goal would be some interesting ways to "stop" a file, by cutting it in some place (might be hard to do due to the file system handling, knowing exactly the size, but uh, why not try ?)

PS: The final goal would eventually be to implement that in c (write a program that write this weird byte on a file and the file size and content is updated like magic)

Comment: On Windows, the antiquated EOF marker `0x1A` is still intepreted to indicate the end of a file when opened *in text mode* but not in binary mode. That key value (Ctrl-Z) also indicates the end of input from the keyboard.

Comment: the usual way is to call close or fclose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, there is no special character that will be interpreted as the end of the file.

However, you can use the Linux system calls [`truncate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) or `ftruncate` to truncate a file to a specific length.